# How to pick up value of the JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, object

I wonder how do I get the text value that is the lyrics in JSON?

The JSON:

```
{
    "type": "exact",
    "art": {
        "id": "3ade68b3g1f86eda3",
        "name": "Madonna",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/madonna\/"
    },
    "mus": [{
        "id": "3ade68b6g8e27fda3",
        "name": "Holiday",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/madonna\/holiday.html",
        "lang": 2,
        "text": "Holiday Celebrate \nHoliday Celebrate \nIf we took a holiday \nTook some time to celebrate \nJust one day out of life \nIt would be, it would be so nice (chorus)\n\nEverybody spread the word \nWe´re gonna have a celebration \nAll across the world \nIn every nation \nIt´s time for the good times \nForget about the bad times, oh yeah \nOne day to come together \nTo release the pressure \nWe need a holiday \n\n(chorus)\n\nYou can turn this world around \nAnd bring back all of those happy days \nPut your troubles down \nIt´s time to celebrate \nLet love shine \nAnd we will find \nA way to come together \nAnd make things better \nWe need a holiday \n\n(chorus)\n\nHoliday Celebrate \nHoliday Celebrate \nHoliday Celebrate \nHoliday Celebrate \nHoliday, Celebration \nCome together in every nation",
        "translate": [{
            "id": "3ade68b6g417afda3",
            "lang": 1,
            "url": "http:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/madonna\/holiday-traducao.html",
            "text": "[Feriado]\nFeriado, comemore \nFeriado, comemore \nSe nós tirássemos uma folga \nTirássemos um dia para comemorar \nSó um dia da vida\nSeria tão, seria tão legal (refrão)\n\nTodo mundo espalhando a notícia \nNós vamos fazer uma comemoração \nPelo mundo inteiro \nEm todas as nações \nÉ hora dos bons momentos \nEsqueça os maus momentos oh yeah \nUm dia para nos unirmos \nPara aliviar a pressão \nNós precisamos de uma folga \n\n(refrão)\n\nVocê pode mudar este mundo \nE trazer de voltas aqueles dias felizes\nAcabe com seus problemas \nÉ hora de comemorar\nDeixe o amor brilhar \nE encontraremos \nUm jeito de nos unirmos \nE fazer as coisas melhor \nPrecisamos de uma folga \n\n(refrão)\n\nFeriado, comemore \nFeriado, comemore \nFeriado, comemore \nFeriado, comemore \nFeriado, celebração\nUnam-se em todas as nações"
        }]
    }],
    "badwords": false
}
```

How to read this in PHP?

How to read the text value in PHP? My code:

```
<?php
$art=$_GET['art'];
$mus=$_GET['mus'];
$json_string = 'http://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?art='.$art.'&mus='.$mus;

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$jsondata2=utf8_encode($jsondata); 
$obj = json_decode($jsondata2);

echo "<b>".$obj->{'art'}->{'name'}."</b>\n";
echo "<br>\n";
echo $obj->['mus']->{'0'}->{'text'};
print $obj;
?>
```

I want to read this:

```
"text":"Holiday Celebrate \nHoliday Celebrate........
```

**EDIT:**

The solution that the user Rocket Hazmat gave me worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Use `$obj->mus[0]->text`.  Get rid of the `{'...'}`, you don't need the `{}` (unless you're doing something like `$obj->{'abc'.$var}`).  Also `['..']` is only for arrays.  So, `$obj->mus` will get you an array, then you use `[0]` to get the 0th element, then `->text` to get the value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You should post an answer so this question can be closed out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read this JSON using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530303/how-to-read-this-json-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
$obj->mus[0]->text
```

Also, while you *can* do `$obj->{'art'}->{'name'}`, I'd suggest:

```
$obj->art->name
```

The `{}` syntax is only useful when you are *generating* a string inside, such as:

```
$obj->{$var.'string'}
```